# Increasing program speedup when using shared memory

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a program that calculates Pi from the Chudnovsky formula. It's written in Java and it uses a shared Vector that is used to save intermediate calculations like factorials and powers that include the index of the element.

However, I believe that since it's a synchronized Vector (thread safe by default) only one thread can read or write to it. So when we have lots of threads, instead of having increasing speedup, we see the computation time becomes constant.

Is there anything that I can do to circumvent that? What to do when there are too many threads reading/writing to the same shared memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the access pattern is lots of reads and occasional writes, you can protect an unsyncronized data structure with a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. It allows multiple readers, but only a single writer.

Depending on your implementation, you might also benefit from using a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

You *might* be able to cheat a bit and use either an `AtomicIntegerArray` or an `AtomicReferenceArray` of `Futures/CompletionStages`.

Comment: The HashMap was really a good idea. I had totally forgotten about that, when it was the obvious perfect choice for storing most of my already calculated stuff

Answer (score 1):

Store the results of each thread in a stack. One thread collects results from every thread and adds them together. Of course the stack should not be empty.

If you want multiple threads to work on factorials why not create a thread or two that produce a list of factorial results. Other threads can just look up results if needed.

Comment: This is a good answer, but this doesn't solve my problem entirely. As you can see from Wikipedia, the Chudnovsky formula has factorials in it. So all threads have to have access to some shared memory/vector that calculates those factorials. When one thread calculates some big factorial, the others will need to have access to that to calculate further factorials and so on.

Comment: I expanded my post.

Comment: What do you mean create a list of factorial results? The other threads are dependent on those factorials for calculating elements of the formula. Plus there is no way to guarantee that factorials are going to be calculated faster than the elements of the formula...

Comment: A thread calculates factorials and stores results in a list that can be accessed by other threads. Since calculating factorials cannot be done in parallel, if they are calculated too slowly then that's the limit. But that probably won't happen since calculating the formula needs multiple operations while calculating one more factorial means multiplying once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the same shared memory, you can have multiple threads with individual memories in a stack. Eventually, add all these up together (or occasionally) with one thread!

Comment: Don't just copy answers from others.

Comment: Oh, just noticed. I was typing my answer out while I guess you just posted it and I didn't bother checking.

Comment: Oh k, thought you just copy&pasted it and changed the wording.

Answer (score 0):

If you need high throughput,  you can consider using Disruptor and RingBuffer.

At a crude level you can think of a Disruptor as a multicast graph of queues where producers put objects on it that are sent to all the consumers for parallel consumption through separate downstream queues. When you look inside you see that this network of queues is really a single data structure - a ring buffer.

Each producer and consumer has a sequence counter to indicate which slot in the buffer it's currently working on. Each producer/consumer writes its own sequence counter but can read the others' sequence counters

Few useful links:

https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor

http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/244826/can-someone-explain-in-simple-terms-what-is-the-disruptor-pattern